# Getting error "file is encrypted or not a database" in SQLite DataBase?

Tags: c#, sqlite, encryption

I am using SQLite Database in C# and trying to encrypt it but when I am setting the Password in Connection.SetPassword it is giving me above error.

```
connection.SetPassword("12345");
trans=connection.BeginTransaction();
```

I am getting the error on `BeginTransaction()` method.
Is there any way to resolve it and set password successfully to SQLite Database.

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the connection after setting the password.

Follow this example:

```
 connection = new SQLiteConnection(connString);
 //Set the password
 connection.SetPassword("12345");
 //Open the connection
 connection.Open();
 connection.Close();
```

If you want to connect to the same DB and remove the password then do as following:

```
 connection = new SQLiteConnection(connString);
 connection.SetPassword("12345");
 connection.Open();
 connection.ChangePassword("");
 connection.Close();
```